# Is there any way to save spools generated against a sqlsrv query?

Tags: php, oracle, sqlsrv

I wanted to save spools in a text file using php that are generated against a oracle database query. I had a input box for query and a button that is when pressed executes that query on oracle database and returns the result.

I want to do same for spools but unable to proceed as set echo on before query doesn't work using sqlsrv.

Comment: it is accepting sql plus commands,

Comment: the point is i want to entry query and want the output as a script file.